# How to handle with command to execute only it's subdirectory?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I'm looking for a way of execute command which I can execute some command only under sub directory not command affect to current directory.

```
find -name ":RUN" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

If I got a directory name is `level0` which has sub directory the name is `level1`. and I run the above example command at `level0` directory then not only `level1` directory but also `level0` affected by command.

How do I handle with that command only affect to `level1` directory at `level0` execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
find   -something …
```

you are effectively saying

```
find . -something …
```

i.e., searching starting in **`.`** (the current directory). 
You want to search only in subdirectories,
so do

```
find ./*/ -name ":RUN" -exec rm -rf {} ;
```

This will not find subdirectories whose names *begin with* **`.`**. 
If you want to include such directories, and you are using bash,
do `shopt -s dotglob` first.

P.S. Naively, `find */ -…` is equivalent to `find ./*/ -…`. 
It’s safer to use `./*/` in case there are files
whose names begin with **`-`**.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
find . -path './*/*' -type d -name ':RUN' -exec echo rm -rf -- {} +
```

You can also replace `-path './*/*'` with its equivalent `-mindepth 2`.